# Visual Studio | My MySQL Update Query is not working.

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio

After looking through a few articles about it, i've come to a conclusion that there is something wrong with my code that may or may not tinker with the UPDATE MySQL query.

I'm trying to update a value which resembles a currency, but it has no effect whats so ever.

The code activates through a button, in addition to this the output is, "Bits have been transferred."

```
        else if (function == "transfer")
            {
                myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from test.auth where id = '" + Int32.Parse(materialSingleLineTextField3.Text) + "' ;", myConn);
                MySqlDataReader reader = myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

                Int32 count = 0;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    count += 1;
                }

                if (count == 1)
                {
                    myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("update test.auth SET bits = bits + '" + double.Parse(materialSingleLineTextField4.Text) + "' where id = '" + Int32.Parse(materialSingleLineTextField3.Text) + "' ;", myConn);
                    materialFlatButton6.Text = "Bits have been transferred!";
                }
                else
                {
                    materialFlatButton6.Text = "No Token was found!";
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: You're not actually executing the command anywhere.

Comment: My bad, it said i had to wait 4 minutes so i went AFK, i completely forgot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute this second query (Change `myConn` to your `MySqlConnection` you've initiated earlier in the program):

```
if (count == 1)
{
    var command = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE test.auth SET bits = bits + @bits WHERE id = @id;", myConn);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bits", materialSingleLineTextField4.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", materialSingleLineTextField3.Text);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    materialFlatButton6.Text = "Bits have been transferred!";
}
```

Comment: Now what if _materialSingleLineTextField4.Text = "ABC";_ ? And also don't forget to explain that this kind of string concatenation is a disaster waiting to happen

Comment: Ah, you have to execute it, thank you very much!
EDIT: Also i had to close the reader just before too just to add.

Comment: @Steve I've updated the answer with binding parameters.

Comment: Also i understand that i need to improve textfields but for now i want to focus on functionality. Thanks anyway,